# Android Hexagon shape button having hexagon touch bounds

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, button

I want to create a hexagon shape button in android so that it's touch area does not overlaps (on the right) ie.I want heaxagon touch bound not a rectangle touch bound. I tried to use image view but it does not excludes tranparent(shown in blue, left). Is there any clickable object which is defined by xml shape/path. please can anyone show me xml shape/path part for just one button if its possible or any other method.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out [this](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview)

[image]

```
<com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.{ClassName}
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/neo"
    app:siBorderWidth="8dp"
    app:siBorderColor="@color/darkgray"/>
```

**Attributes:**

- `siBorderColor` border color
- `siBorderWidth` border width in dp
- `siBorderAlpha` alpha value of the border between 0.0-1.0
- `siStrokeCap` border stroke cap type butt|round|square
- `siStrokeJoin` border stroke join type bevel|miter|round
- `siSquare` set width and height to the minimum of the given values
  true|false
- `siShape` a reference to an SVG. This is used by ShapeImageView, not
  the subclasses of it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no system view that would do custom shapes for you. You need to create custom view: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html and in its `onTouchEvent()` determine if user's tap is inside or outside clickable area and act accordingly.